# Stuck in global structure of my quiz app

Tags: android

I recently started programming in Android, and as one of my beginning practise projects I am trying to build a logo quiz app. The idea: You see a splash screen after opening the app (play game - about). Play game takes you to a new activity called LevelSelector.java where you can choose the level you want to play. Clicking on a level takes you to another new Activity Level.java. 
I created a SQLite db with 20 questions in it which I install with a DBHelper.java class, every question also has a level column.

However, I get lost in my global structure. Since I work with different levels I don't want to make a new class for every level. I guess I have to make some kind of instance of a seperated class, or how can I solve this? I guess I lost the overview due to my lack of programming in android, but I figured the best way to learn it is (after I watched tutorials) to build an app myself..

Hope somebody can help me so I can go further with my programming, cause I am just stuck right now...

Comment: You don't want to create a class for every level or create a DBHelper for every level?

Comment: Would this work for you? Pass the level from level selector to level activity via intent.  Use the level with your db helper to retrieve only the records for that level.  Use a single level activity to show the data for any level.  It looks like you don't need any special classes because at any level your app behaves the same.  The only difference is the set of questions.

Comment: And I suppose I have to create a new DbHelper within my level Activity? What the DbHelper does is also checking if there is already a DB present.. maybe a little bit overkill if it has to do this for every level again or am I wrong?

Comment: Close your DBHelper in your LevelSelector.java activity before you open the level activity and then open a new one in your Level Activity. You could alternatively make it a singleton class, but I would suggest to do the first.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to go with this info. If it is not working out, I'll let you know :). Maybe another small question, is it also the best to save the score in the Database (people can guess multiple times, the more they guess the less score they eventually will have) or to store this in the sharedpreferences for example?

Comment: have your DbHelper extend SQLiteOpenHelper and maintain a reference to it from your application instead of your activity.. have a getDb method on the application to access it.. then you never have to close it. maintaining Db state is a pain, this gets around it.. each level is just an object.. maybe it had a List<Question> as a property but there is no real difference from one level to the next.. storing your scores in the db would make it easier to do certain things but shared prefs is fine for a basic display.  If someone clears cache you lose both anyways.

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial how to handle this, I mean, maintaining a reference from my application? Cause I am not sure how to do this...